# Express - POST request pending

Tags: node.js, express

I have a form to register users, but post request is not working

I've checked bodyparser, consign includes order, added enctype to form and still do not work

The route is working, cause it calls my controller, but as you can see at console image, it goes to the controller with undefined req, althought url params are defined at devtools

server.js:

```
const express = require('express'); 
const consign = require('consign');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv-safe').load();  

const app = express(); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './app/paginas'); 

app.use(express.static('./app/publico/'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressValidator());

consign(/* {cwd: 'app'} */)
    .include('config/conectarBD.js')
    .then('app/modelos')
    .then('app/controles')
    .then('app/rotas')
    .into(app);


/* consign()
    .include('app/rotas')
    .then('config/conectarBD.js')
    .then('app/modelos')
    .then('app/controles')
    .into(app); */

console.log('Instância do app criada');

module.exports = app;
```

form.ejs:

```
<div class="row" id="form_registro">
                <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3 text-center">
                        <form action="/registrar" method="POST">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Registro</legend>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form-r-email">Nome:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Seu nome">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form-r-email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
                                    placeholder="Seu email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="form-r-senha">Senha:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha"
                                    placeholder="Sua senha">
                            </div>
                            <!-- TODO implementar -->
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck2">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Lembre de mim</label>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrar</button>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div>
                            Já tem uma conta?
                            <a href="#" id="logar">Registrar!</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

route login.js:

```
module.exports = function(application) {
    application.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        console.log('Rota pegaPaginaLogin');
        application.app.controles.login.pegaPaginaLogin(application, req, res);
    });
    application.post('/admin/logar', function(req, res) {
        console.log('Rota /admin/logar');
        application.app.controles.login.logaUsuario(application, req, res);
    });

    application.post('/registrar', function(req, res) {
        console.log('Rota registrar');
        console.log('req.body >>>' + req.body);
        res.status(500).send('testing');
        application.app.controles.login.registraUsuario(application, req, res);
    });
}
```

controller registraUsuario:

```
module.exports.registraUsuario = function (application, req, res) {
    console.log('Controller registraUsuario');
    console.log('REQ....' + req)
    var usuario = req.body;

    /** Validação do formulário */
    //TODO validar formatos
    req.assert('nome', 'Nome é obrigatório').notEmpty();
    req.assert('email', 'Email é obrigatório').notEmpty();
    req.assert('senha', 'Senha é obrigatório').notEmpty();

    var errosValidacao = req.validationErrors();

    console.log(errosValidacao);

    if (errosValidacao) {
        res.render('login', {
            validacao: errosValidacao,
            usuario: usuario
        });
        return;
    }

    /** Conexão com banco */
    var conexao = application.config.conectarBD();
    var novoUsuario = new application.app.modelos.UsuariosModel(conexao);

    novoUsuario.getUsuario(usuario, function (error, result) {
        console.log(result);

        novoUsuario.novoUsuario(usuario);
    });

}
```

model UsuariosModel:

```
function UsuariosModel(conexao) {
    this._conexao = conexao;
}

/** Se usuário existir, retorna a id_usuario */
UsuariosModel.prototype.getUsuario = function (usuario, callback) {
console.log('Model getUsuario');
this._conexao.query('SELECT id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email = "' + usuario.email + ' and senha = "' + usuario.senha + '"');
```

}

```
UsuariosModel.prototype.novoUsuario = function (usuario, callback) {
    var hoje = Date.now();
    this._conexao.query('INSERT INTO usuarios SET ?', usuario, callback);
}

module.exports = function () {
    return UsuariosModel;
};
```

console:

[image]

error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post code for `application.app.controles.login.registraUsuario`

Comment: there you go...

Comment: i think i'm scaping the sql quotes wrong, made some changes and i'm getting sql syntax error for password

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server code is not calling `response.send`.

Replace your code with this to test:

```
application.post('/registrar', function(req, res) {
        console.log('Rota registrar');
        console.log('REQ.query....' + req.params.name);
        res.status(500).send('testing');
        //application.app.controles.login.registraUsuario(application, req, res);
    });
```

In `registraUsuario`, you need to call `send` with your response/status code. Yourclient will block until send is called, or a timeout occurs.

Comment: So now you need to keep digging to find out why the commented out function is not calling `send`.  You probably have logic that forgets to call it, or exception is thrown, perhaps in an async block,  and not caught.  Wrap your code not posted in try/catch, and call send in the catch.

Comment: Call response.status(200).send() or response.send() from your function if you want to return success.

Comment: yo can now also call `sendStatus(500)`.

Answer (score 1):

Close your database connection I will facing same issues once you close db connection the issue will be solved

```
Try {
  ...
} Catch {
  ...
} finally {
  Connection.close()
}
```